# I can't login with facebook in laravel socialite , where it works for google and github

Tags: facebook-login, laravel-7, laravel-socialite

the error it shows when i click to login:
    [Error message from facebook, i think](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3wHG.png)

#### Error it Shows

GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException
Client error: `POST https://graph.facebook.com/v3.3/oauth/access_token` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response: {"error":{"message":"Can't load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this (truncated...)
http://socialite.com/login/facebook/callback?error_code=1349187&error_message=Insecure%20Login%20Blocked%3A%20You%20can%27t%20get%20an%20access%20token%20or%20log%20in%20to%20this%20app%20from%20an%20insecure%20page.%20Try%20re-loading%20the%20page%20as%20https%3A%2F%2F